# How to determine the largest length of Progress OpenEdge ABL fields

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

In OpenEdge ABL / Progress 4GL, a field can be defined with a FORMAT, but that is only the default format for it to be displayed. Thus, a CHARACTER field with FORMAT 'X(10)' could store thousands of characters past the first ten.

The database I'm using contains millions of rows in some of the tables I'm concerned with. **Is there any system table or Progress-internal program I can use to determine the longest length of a given field?** I'm looking for anything more efficient than full-table scans. I'm on Progress OpenEdge 11.5.

Comment: I'm not sure what the benefit is of 'fixing' the formats, unless, as Tom suggests it's actually a SQL width issue. Can you expand on the reasons a bit?

Comment: Good call out @jdpjamesp. The database in question does not have any programs making SQL queries on it. My concern is ETL from this Progress database to an Oracle database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"dbtool" will scan the db and find fields whose width exceeds the "sql width".  By default that is 2x the format that was defined for character fields.

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496/

Of course it has to scan the table to do that so it may not meet your "more efficient than table scans" criteria.  FWIW dbtool is reasonably efficient.

If the fields that you are concerned about are problematic because of potential SQL access you might also want to look into "authorized data truncation" via the -SQLTruncateTooLarge parameter which will truncate the data on the fly.

Another option would be -SQLWidthUpdate which automatically adjusts the SQL width on the fly.  That requires an upgrade to at least 11.6.

Both of these might solve your problem without periodic table scans.

Comment: Thank's, Tom! The documentation says it has various options, including specific RECIDs and Tables (posting this as I was curious about it).

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually the character format you want to adjust to match the data, I suppose what you could do is to use dbtool to adjust the SQL width of all the fields, and then set the character format to be half the SQL width.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but I upvoted, since it's a good idea for others! I'm not concerned with SQL width in the Progress database itself, but the definitions of the fields in the Oracle database.